# "Пусть и... однако" внутри предложения: что с запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

> Так Буонарроти обретёт великого мецената, готового следовать за
>   полётом его космической фантазии, и вместе с тем того узурпатора,
>   который навсегда прикуёт художника к идее создания колоссальной
>   гробницы. До того момента лишь императоры древнего мира смели
>   увековечивать себя в постройках масштабных мавзолеев, утверждая таким
>   образом своё бессмертие. **Христиане, пусть и заимствовали традицию
>   мемориала, однако в основу этой архитектурной формы была положена иная
>   идея**: не прославление личных заслуг, но напоминание о той общности,
>   что роднит живущего и ушедшего верующего – того, кто уже обрёл
>   блаженство, и того, кто только борется за своё спасение.

Пожалуйста, увидите ошибки - кричите!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Хотя христиане и заимствовали традицию мемориала,** однако в основу этой архитектурной формы была положена иная идея: не прославление личных заслуг, но напоминание о той общности, что роднит живущих и ушедших **верующих – тех, кто уже обрёл блаженство, и тех, кто только борется за своё спасение.**

Пояснение (как я думаю)

1) Существует союзный аналог **ПУСТЬ, ПУСТЬ И.** Он  ставится перед  **обособленным оборотом**, например:

Теперь можно было, **пусть и очень приблизительно**, оценить, с какой стороны двигался хищник. [Александр Зайцев.  // «Знание -- сила», 2003]

Это скорее политический проект, **пусть и блестящий**. [Александр Рыклин.  2003.04.08]

2) Существует составной союз **ПУСТЬ И...НО/ЗАТО** (аналог ХОТЯ И...НО), который применяется в предложении **с однородными членами**:

Госпиталь был бабий, хоть и командовал им мужик, Женский день тут справлялся **пусть и не каждый год, зато торжественно и шумно.** [Виктор Астафьев. Пролетный гусь (2000)]

Ну а пока он спит у полузатухшего костерка, который серым дымком льнёт к нему, отжимая **пусть и редких, но надоедливых** комаров. [Виктор Астафьев. Затеси (1999) // «Новый Мир», 2000]

3) В сложном предложении обычно используется союз ХОТЯ...НО, при этом **хотя** стоит в начале первого предложения.

Comment: Шаронушка, я не поняла, что мне делать... 8-( Зачем запятая у *общности, что роднит живущего и ушедшего верующего – того, кто уже обрёл блаженство, и того, кто только борется за своё спасение,* - ето ж пара: живущий-ушедшей - обретший-борющийся...

Comment: Да, Вы, наверное,  правы, запятая не нужна. Это будет соответствовать грамматике, но интонация здесь немного другая (пауза более длительная, чем обычно для присоединительных оборотов).

Comment: Шаронка, мне больше про ***интонацию*** - ни-ни! "Сем тибе" (угроза Бабы Яги очередной Алёнушке, взяла на заметку, как тая хозяйка). )))

Comment: Нет проблем, пусть будет только грамматика.